# update-help and save-help doesn't work

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

**Still return 'Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.' I don't know WHY :(**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Save-Help -DestinationPath "C:\Users\Frank\Documents\PowerShellHelp" -Force

PS C:\Windows\system32> Update-Help -SourcePath "C:\Users\Frank\Documents\PowerShellHelp" -force

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Help Get-FileHash
```

> NAME
>       Get-FileHash
>
> SYNTAX
>       Get-FileHash [-Path]  [-Algorithm  {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 | RIPEMD160}] 
>   []
>
> ```
> Get-FileHash -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Algorithm <string> {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 | RIPEMD160}]
> ```
>
> []
>
> ```
> Get-FileHash -InputStream <Stream> [-Algorithm <string> {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 | RIPEMD160}]
> ```
>
> []
>
> ALIASES
>       None
>
> **REMARKS
>       Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.**
>           -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
>           -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Get-FileHash -Online" or
>              go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517145.

Comment: You might be able to see what's going on when it fails with `Update-Help -Debug`

Comment: Debug return modules are updated…

Answer (score 1):

-Force

Overrides the once-per-day limitation, version checking, and the 1 GB per module limit.

**Without this parameter, Update-Help runs only once in each 24-hour period, downloads are limited to 1 GB of uncompressed content per module and help files are installed only when they are newer than the files on the computer.**

The once-per-day limit protects the servers that host the help files and makes it practical for you to add an Update-Help command to your Windows PowerShell profile without incurring the resource cost of repeated connections or downloads.

To update help for a module in multiple UI cultures without the Force parameter, include all UI cultures in the same command, such as:

```
Update-Help -Module PSScheduledJobs -UICulture en-US, fr-FR, pt-BR
```